# Where is the Manage Content and Structure under site settings in 2013?

Tags: 2013, global-navigation

Where is the Manage Content and Structure under site settings in 2013 so I can hide the global navigation?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **Site Setting**s page you will see **Content and structur**e under **Site Administration**
[image]

Or directly browse the page `/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx`

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143595/how-to-remove-global-navigation-from-2013

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have Publishing features enabled there is no link to "Content and structure" in Site settings.

You should be able to reach it through:

```
http://YourSiteUrl/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx
```

Not sure how you mean this is related to hiding the global navigation though.

Comment: Great thanks, The reason why I was asking was because I created a custom banner for my site but the global navigation moved to the middle of my banner and I'm not sure how to hide it. thanks again and sorry a little new at development.

Comment: I don't mind the seach bar on the right hand side but the rest has got to go